# Android release apk not installing after upgrading to compileSdkPreview UpsideDownCake

Tags: android

I've upgraded the compile-sdk-version from Tiramisu to UpsideDownCake and the release apk not working on any of the devices.

Tried the changes given on Android sdk upgrade link for compile-sdk-version upsidedowncake

Comment: What `minSdkVersion` have you set?

Comment: added minSdk 24